# Increasing spaces between sections

Tags: spacing, cv

I would like to improve the spacing between sections of this column, but entering **\ newline** is not working

[image]

**Curriculo.tex**

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Pacotes e Configurações
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % Para Papel A4
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\profilepic{Leandro.png} % Profile picture

\cvname{Leandro} % Seu nome
\cvjobtitle{Engenheiro Mecânico} % Carreira

\cvdate{10/Janeiro/1978} % Data de Nascimento
\cvaddress{Brasil} % País
\cvnumberphone{+55(12)xxxxxxxxx} % Telefone
\cvsite{http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnBvTLPG9M1dbqA-sxN3UmA} % Site pessoal
\cvmail{leandromcarvalho.com.br} % Email
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Sobre mim
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\sobremim{Aqui posso escrever um texto enorme sobre mim}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Habilidades
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Habilidades com valores entre 0 e 6
\skills{{pursuer of rabbits/5},{good manners/4},{outgoing/4.3},{polite/4},{Java/0.01},{lovely/4},{narcissistic/3}}

\makeprofile

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Interesses
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interesses}

Aqui pode-se escrever para qual vaga deseja se candidatar

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Educação
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Educação}

\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{Até o momento}{Pós-graduação}{Nome da Escola1}{MBA em Engenharia}
    \twentyitem{2004-2015}{Graduação}{Nome da Escola2}{Engenharia mecânica}
    \twentyitem{2000-2003}{Curso Técnico}{Nome da Escola3}{Técnico Mecânico}
    \twentyitem{1998-2000}{Ensino médio}{Nome da Escola4}{Ensino médio cursado}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Publicações
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Publicações}

\begin{twentyshort}
    \twentyitemshort{2015}{Título da sua publicação 1}
    \twentyitemshort{2014}{Título da sua publicação 2}
    \twentyitemshort{2009}{Título da sua publicação 3}
    \twentyitemshort{2003}{Título da sua publicação 4}
    \twentyitemshort{2001}{Título da sua publicação 5}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Recompensas
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Eventos}

\begin{twentyshort}
    \twentyitemshort{1998}{Nome do evento1}
    \twentyitemshort{1996}{Nome do evento1}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Experiências
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experiências}

\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{2008}{Nome da Empresa1}{Empresa}{Escreva aqui1}
    \twentyitem{2005}{Nome da Empresa2}{Empresa}{Escreva aqui2}
    \twentyitem{2000}{Nome da Empresa3}{Empresa}{Escreva aqui3}

\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Outras Informações
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Outras Informações}

\subsection{Dados complementares}

Pode-se escrever algumas informaçções importantes neste último capítulo

\end{document}
```

**twentysecondcv.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2015/02/28 CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%PACKAGES%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\usetikzlibrary{calc}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB0B00}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{cerulean}{HTML}{007BA7}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}
\definecolor{maindarkgray}{HTML}{B3B3B3}
\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{asidecolor}{sidecolor}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
  \colorlet{asidecolor}{sidecolor}
\fi


\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Profile left SideBar %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\newcommand{\imsize}{\linewidth}
\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale
\renewcommand{\imsize}{0.618\linewidth}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}%
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/600}%


\newcommand{\profilesection}[2]{{\noindent\color{black!80} \huge #1 \rule[0.15\baselineskip]{#2}{1pt} \vspace{1pt}}}


\newcommand{\cvdate}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvdate}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvmail}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvmail}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvnumberphone}[1]{\renewcommand{\givennumberphone}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvaddress}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvaddress}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsite}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvsite}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sobremim}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenaboutme}{  \justifying#1}}
\newcommand{\profilepic}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenprofilepic}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvname}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvjobtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvjobtitle}{#1}}

\newcommand{\givencvname}{REQUIRED!}
\newcommand{\givencvdate}{}
\newcommand{\givencvmail}{}
\newcommand{\givennumberphone}{}
\newcommand{\givencvaddress}{} 
\newcommand{\givenaboutme}{}
\newcommand{\givenprofilepic}{}
\newcommand{\givencvsite}{}
\newcommand{\givencvjobtitle}{}



\newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*\round[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=north west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=1.6pt, minimum size=5.5mm,
    text height=3.6mm,  fill=#2,#2,text=white](char){#1} ;}

\newcommand\skills[1]{ 

\renewcommand{\givenskill}{
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}
{
  \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,-\i) rectangle (6,-\i+0.4);
  \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,-\i) rectangle (1.2*\y,-\i+0.4);
  \node [above right ] at (0,-\i+0.4) {\x};
  \foreach \z in {0,1,2,...,10}
  {
    \coordinate (A\z) at ($(0,-\i)+(1.2*\z*0.5cm,0)$) {};
    \ifodd\z
        \draw[white] ($(A\z)$) -- ($(A\z)+(0,2.5pt)$);
    \else
        \draw[white] ($(A\z)$) -- ($(A\z)+(0,5pt)$);
    \fi
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\newcommand{\givenskill}{}

\newcommand\skillstext[1]{ 

\renewcommand{\giventextskill}{
\begin{flushleft}
\noindent
\foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}
{ 
\x$ \star $\y
}
\end{flushleft}
}
}


\newcommand{\giventextskill}{}



\newcommand{\makeprofile}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9.90cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace{13pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);

        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\givenprofilepic}};
\end{tikzpicture}

{\Huge\color{mainblue}\givencvname}

\begin{flushright}
{\Large\color{black!80}\givencvjobtitle}
\end{flushright}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \givencvaddress\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givennumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \givennumberphone\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \href{\givencvsite}{\textcolor{cerulean}\givencvsite}}\\
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\givencvmail}{\givencvmail}}
\end{tabular}


\profilesection{Sobre Mim}{3.2cm}
\givenaboutme


\profilesection{Habilidade}{5cm}
\givenskill
\giventextskill
\noindent
\scriptsize
\noindent


\end{flushleft}
\end{textblock}
\vspace{-10pt}
 }




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Section Color box %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
   \round{#1#2#3}{
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        maingray\or%
        mainblue\or%
        maingray\or%
        mainblue\else%
        maingray\fi%
    }%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par%\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {%
  \large\color{headercolor} #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List twenty environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
  \hspace{5pt}#1&\parbox[t]{11.5cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize#3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Small twenty List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{twentyshort}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\twentyitemshort}[2]{%
  \hspace{5pt}#1&\parbox[t]{11.5cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
  }\\}


%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page Setting %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[left=7.3cm,top=0.1cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=0.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Maybe try `\titlespacing{\section}{...}` from \titlesec` (see details in the package documentation)?

Comment: It would be convenient to insert this parameter into the class, right?

Comment: You may. But as it seems to use the default configuration of the `article` class, you may as well add it to your preamble.

Comment: IT'S OK. I will do

Comment: If you've found it, I want to draw your attention on the simplified syntax, described in §3.2.

Comment: \titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]

Comment: I mean that before-sep and after-sep have minus and plus  parts 'they're rubber lengths), and this can be done automatically  using the `*{n}`, where n means n `ex`, with the plus and minus parts added by the package.

Answer (score 0):

The CLS file is where all the functions are defined. You can change the vertical spacing by playing with the spacing values defined there. Here is an example:

```
\newcommand{\profilesection}[2]{{\noindent\color{black!80} \huge #1 \rule[0.15\baselineskip]{#2}{1pt} \vspace{1pt}}}
```

Here you can change the value for `\vspace{1pt}` to whatever you like. Please note that hard-spacing like `\\` or `\newline` do not work here in the main tex file.